# Intermittent Ora 1722 errors caused by to_number

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I'm working on an issue that I just can't figure out, but I believe I made some progress today. In a where clause, there is the following code:

```
AND to_number(REPLACE(TRANSLATE ( decode( INSTR(hra_ans.answer_text, '.',1 , 2), 0 , UPPER(hra_ans.answer_text) , 0),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTWVXYZ+<>:',' '), ' ','')) >= 10
```

Now, this hra_ans.answer_text column can contain anything from '>' to '>15' to '13.68' to 'no results' to '1.2.3.4', etc. The invalid number error only occurs intermittently, not every time. I've tried replacing Translate with Regexp_Replace using an expression of '[^0-9.]', but that doesn't solve the problem either. I found this on SO:

[Here is a similar question I stumbled accross.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848146/invalid-number-error-cant-seem-to-get-around-it)

In that post, it appears that the error can be caused because there is no definite order of operations. Is it likely that I'm encountering the same situation?  If not, would else might cause this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can declare a new function, the simplest option is probably to do something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_to_number( p_str IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  l_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    l_num := to_number( p_str );
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
      l_num := NULL;
  END;

  RETURN l_num;
END my_to_number;
```

and then use that in your query

```
AND my_to_number( hra_ans.answer_text ) >= 10
```

I'll wager that there is data in the `ANSWER_TEXT` column that isn't getting turned into a valid number by your string processing functions.

Comment: Assuming there are no characters in the data that would not be handled by TRANSLATE, do you know why the error would still occur?

Comment: @mpminnich - My initial hunch was that there were characters that were not handled by the TRANSLATE function.  If we rule that out, there could be issues with things like NLS settings where the intermittent errors occur because some sessions use European NLS settings (where the decimal separator is the comma rather than the period).  But I'd tend to wager that it was more likely that the data itself has the problems (i.e. a European user entered 13,68 rather than 13.68 or an American user entered 1,234.68 and you're not handling a character like the comma).

Comment: I'll give the function a try and if it works, I'll accept your answer. If not, I'll be back! :-) Thanks.